# GameObject colliding with Sprite?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a sprite and it's name is "princess" and when a cube touches my sprite
I want the princess to be destroyed. I added a rigidbody, and a box collider, but for some reason the cube just goes through the princess sprite.

The cube is generated with code so it's name is "Cube" according to the hierachy so I wrote this code

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
   if(collision.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    } 
}
```

I think Destroy(this.gameObject) would destroy the princess, but they're not even colliding.

Any ideas?

Here is what the "game" looks like.

[Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ql1V.png)

Comment: You have to use `OnCollisionEnter2D` for sprites to collide

Comment: @Hristo I just changed it, and it's still going through the princess :(

Comment: Both of your objects need to have a collider (2D in your case). Make sure that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you checked the "is trigger" inside the box colliders.
You should use tag because if you spawn multiple cubes the will have names like "Cube (1)" and so on.
You need to use collider2d

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Cube")
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

both of your object needs to have box collider2d and rigidbody2d and not set to "is trigger". example:
[image]

Comment: it's only spawning one cube at a time, im gonna give them all random speeds. I attatched a photo to the question to see what the game looks like,idk if it helps. I changed it to your code, and its still going through the princess.

Comment: @fwefwf  look at the updated answer. by the way ,do you have any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Destroy(this.gameObject) is working for own object where

collision.gameObject.setActive("False") is working for collide object

This code is working on my game. where "Player" is my Sprite tag. And make sure 'Is Trigger' is checked for your Cube

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```

OR alternatively in your case below code you could use in Cube script then might be work

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "princess")
    {
        collision.gameObject.setActive("False")
    }
}
```